# How to return the maximum subarray using brute force?

Tags: java, arrays, brute-force

This is my code for returning the maximum subarray SUM using brute force, but would it be possible to return the actual subarray instead?

```
public static int[] findMaximumSubArray(int[] nums){
    int curMax = nums[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int sum = nums[i];
        curMax = Math.max(sum,  curMax);
        
        for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            sum += nums[j];
            curMax = Math.max(sum,  curMax);
        }
    }
    return curMac;
```

Comment: Yes - just keep track of the start and end indices instead of keeping track of the sum. Don't just set the maximum sum but rather check if the new sum is larger and update the max start/end indices when it is.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to keeping track of the current maximum sum, you should also keep track of the current maximum sub array. You can easily do this by just keeping track of its start and end positions.

```
// assume non-empty array
int maxStart = 0;
int maxEnd = 0;
int curMax = nums[0];
```

Rather than using `Math.max`, expand that into an `if (sum > curMax)` check so that you can also set `maxStart` and `maxEnd` in there:

In the outer loop, since it finds the start position, replace `Math.max` with:

```
if (sum > curMax) {
    curMax = sum;
    maxStart = i;
    maxEnd = i;
}
```

In the inner loop, since it finds both the start position and the end position, replace the `Math.max` call with:

```
if (sum > curMax) {
    curMax = sum;
    maxStart = i;
    maxEnd = j;
}
```

Finally, return a copy of the specified range of the array:

```
return Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, maxStart, maxEnd + 1);
```

Note that the subarray with the maximum sum is not unique. For example, the array `{ 0, 1, 0 }` has 4 subarrays that all add up to 1. This algorithm finds the shortest among the ones that starts the earliest.

Full code looks like this:

```
public static int[] findMaximumSubArray(int[] nums) {
    int maxStart = 0;
    int maxEnd = 0;
    int curMax = nums[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int sum = nums[i];
        if (sum > curMax) {
            curMax = sum;
            maxStart = i;
            maxEnd = i;
        }

        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            sum += nums[j];
            if (sum > curMax) {
                curMax = sum;
                maxStart = i;
                maxEnd = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, maxStart, maxEnd + 1);
}
```